# Woocommerce Category product count when search string is present

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I get the total product match on certain category when search string (`?s='productSearch'`) is present?

I am working on an existing plugin which is sidebar advanced search widget. All category show the product they own, but when adding query/search string, it remains the same.

Example:

Bracelets(1163)

Bracelets Category total count 1163 product but when search for warfarin on Bracelets, it counts 150 product, but Bracelets category still counts 1163.

I should show 150, How Can add this filter?

Comment: Did you check this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-predictive-search/

Comment: This plugin has _Predictive Search_ logic so this may be useful as per your requirement.

Comment: how is this `Bracelets(1163)` coded? without knowing how it was coded, we can't give you an answer... we can guess but our guess might be something you already did or not the right guess. It would be better if you could show us what have you done so far to resolved this problem. ;)